# running jboss behind apache - different servers

Tags: apache-2.2, jboss

How can I setup apache forward `host.company.com` -> `server.company.com/host`

Where `server.company.com` is the Apache server.

We have other services running like

```
service1. company.com -> server.company.com/service1
service2. company.com -> server.company.com/service2
service3. company.com -> server.company.com/service3
```

(these services run on the same server as the apache)

Which works fine.

As mentioned in the beginning, I want to setup apache forwarding so that if I try to access `host.company.com/customerX` then it should be forwarded to `server.company.com/host/customerX`, where `X = 1,2,3...`

Where this customerX runs on other server.

My experience in setting this is limited and could someone guide me how to set this up

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by "forwarding", but the traditional method is to use a proxy to a jboss backend.

Read this to get you started: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Jboss, so I am uncertain if you can simply connect to AJP there. However in case you can't you can try and achieve that using mod_proxy. Should go like this

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
   ProxyPass /host http://host.company.com/
   ProxyPassReverse /host http://host.company.com/
</IfModule>
```

Keep track of the obligatory security measurements coming along with mod_proxy. You can place this snippet in a `VirtualHost` context for server.company.com

If you can verify that you got AJP running on jboss (normally port 8009), you can use the same snippet replacing http:// with ajp:// adding :8009 to the URL.

```
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
   ProxyPass /host ajp://host.company.com:8009/
   ProxyPassReverse /host ajp://host.company.com:8009/
</IfModule>
```